# Polynomials and NSA

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, applications

I'm looking for some applications of criteria of irreducibility of integer polynomials inside and outside mathematics.

I was reading the [CV](http://www.math.sc.edu/~filaseta/FilasetaVita2013.pdf) of Filaseta, a great researcher in this area and he has gained some grants from NSA. Then this makes me think if there are some applications of this matter to computer science.

My question is broader, which are the applications of these criteria of irreducibility such as Eisenstein, Dumas criterion, etc. to the real world or other areas of mathematics?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I smell cryptographic applications

Comment: I also think that data mining will also benefit from this but I'm not sure, you should ask on http://stats.stackexchange.com/ for that or on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ or http://cs.stackexchange.com/ .